# I need to run 2 twaitforfile in the same subjob talend

Tags: database, foreign-keys, etl, talend, file-watcher

I need to run 2 file watchers in the same subjob using talend. Right now If I link them together I get only one file watching running when I run talend.

Below is what I have. Is there a way to execute them together. The reason for this is because im trying to get the Fk from one table into the tmap from another table, so any other suggestion on how to do this is also appreciated: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58876.png)

Answer (score 0):

In one subjob, you can only have one 'beginning' component (the one with the green background). This is the one which will be actually waiting for a file.
 You have to split the subjob in order to have both tWaitForFile running.

You can have one subjob waiting for the first file, then link this first subjob with an 'on subjob OK' link to the second subjob, where you can wait for the second file.